# SDL2 Image to screen issue

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been on the hunt trying to figure out how to get this to execute properly. I've been having trouble finding good documentation on SDL (If anyone has a most necessary goto I would love to check it out).

So, after finding out that `SDL_Flip` and `SDL_SetVideoMode` are extinct while amidst in Lazy Foo's tutorials and finding out it's all about windows now. I can't seem to get an image to the screen still. I'm completely new to SDL (obviously). So, everything compiles fine. I'm compiling in the source directory where the image.bmp is also located, but for some reason the image pointer returns `NULL` and I just get a blank screen when the program executes.

One more thing. I get this error from `SDL_GetError`: "passed a NULL surface". Is that because for what ever reason the image is returning `NULL` or can't be opened?

Here is the source:

```
#include "SDL2\SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* args[]){

SDL_Surface *image = NULL;
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

window = SDL_CreateWindow( "img.cc", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

image = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");

SDL_BlitSurface( image, NULL, screen, NULL );

SDL_FreeSurface( image );
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
if(SDL_GetError != NULL)
{   
    fprintf(stdout,"SDL_GetError: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
}
if(image == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Image is NULL");
}
//Pause
SDL_Delay( 2000 );

//Free the loaded image
SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

//Quit SDL
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you think of first checking if the image loads at all? I.e., directly after `LoadImage`? `GetError` will only report the last error, and it'll happily report "None" if only the very last SDL succeeded.

Comment: @Jongware: That is incorrect: `SDL_GetError()` will keep errors until the error is cleared with `SDL_ClearError()`.  See the documentation: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryError%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I didn't know that -- thanks, it may be handy! But in this case, immediately checking for an error would point out (well...) *immediately* if the image did load or not. Which is what the OP wants to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the .bmp file was incorrect. I had changed the format of the file through gimp as .bmp, but possibly I may have did something wrong. Because, after reviewing a similar problem online I re-saved the file with paint and it worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you run this command,

```
image = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
```

it loads the image from the *current directory* from the perspective of the application.  This may not be the directory that you compiled in!

### Add error checking

First, always check for errors, even if it's just an `assert()`…

```
image = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
if (!image) {
    fail("Could not load image");
}
```

Define `fail()`...

```
#include <string>
void fail(const char *msg) {
    std::string text = msg;
    const char *err = SDL_GetError();
    if (err) {
        text.append(": ");
        text.append(err);
    }
    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(
        SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR,
        "An error occurred",
        text.c_str(),
        nullptr);
    std::exit(1);
}
```

Since you said that `image` is null, my guess is that this will print out something like a "file not found" message.

### Finding your files

There are a couple common ways to locate files:

- If you need to keep data files with your application, consider using [`SDL_GetBasePath()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetBasePath) to find them.  Using this means that you have to put your files in a known location relative to the application binary (not the source code).
- You can also load files relative to the current directory, but you need to make sure that the current directory is the one you want when you run your game.  For example, if you are using an IDE like Visual Studio or Xcode, you will have to set the current directory in the debug settings for your project.

Since you didn't tell us what platform your are developing on, it's a bit hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: I'm using windows minGW.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with minGW! Are you using an IDE, are you double-clicking the program, or are you running it from the command line?  Each option affects the current directory differently.